# Rollback misconfigured network settings in systemd using etckeeper?

Tags: shell-script, systemd, systemd-networkd, etckeeper

I was thinking how to automatically rollback network misconfigurations with etckeeper and systemd.

Workflow:

```
# etckeeper commit
# $EDITOR /etc/systemd/network/wired.network
# systemctl restart systemd-networkd
You broke the network! I'm calling your mom!
Here's your broken config:
$(cat broken_file)
$(etckeeper vcs reset -- old_config_file)

# $EDITOR /etc/systemd/network/wired.network
# systemctl restart systemd-networkd
#
```

Currently i'm stuck how to hook into restart event.

```
gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop --object-path /org/freedesktop
```

Doesn't output anything when running

```
# systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Script itself could be something like:

- hook into systemd `restart` and if possible, directly into `restart systemd-networkd`
- Read the hook information if it contains that restart failed, otherwise read `systemctl is-active systemd-networkd`
- Rename broken file to $file.broken
- Restore: `etckeeper vcs reset -- $file`
- `systemctl stop automatic-net-configuration-rollback.service` (so that there's no infinite loop)
- `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`

  - Works -> `systemctl start automatic-net-configuration-rollback.service`
  - Doesn't -> `echo Rollbacked config file doesn't work either. Repair manually and start automatic rollback after it works.`

Is this possible and/or does systemd already have this kind of service built-in or has someone made one already? My google searches came up empty.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4666